# Автоматический переход на другое Activity спустя определенное количество времени

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Опишу ситуацию. При открытии приложения появляется Activity в которой находится картинка с прелоудером (PreloaderActivity), которая должна пропасть через определенное время, например 3 секунды, и открыться приложение (MainActivity).
Пример приложения - Evernote Food.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Это классическая заставка. Кода - куча. Вот к [примеру](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-simple-splash-screen.html).

Comment: в PreloaderActivity запустить AsyncTask, который будет висеть n секунд, в onPostExecute вызвать MainActivity и finish для PreloaderActivity. Например так можно. В своем приложении я делал слегка по другому, но смысл такой же был. В основном потоке ни в коем случае не делайте паузу, может вылезти ANR